# Downgrade Java 1.7 to Java 1.5

Tags: java

I am now on Ubuntu 14.04, and my Java version is java version "1.7.0_55". How can I remove 1.7 and install java 1.5. I tried several tutorials, but they are old and none of them worked for me.

Comment: so what tutorials?  We need to know exactly what you have done so that you can get an answer you havent tried.  Can you explain why you want Java 1.5 - that is not supported and is a security risk to install this.

Comment: I want JDK 1.5(.0.22), instead of current JDK 1.7 to run specific software. Well I tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672795/how-do-i-downgrade-java-from-1-6-0-to-1-5-0-in-ubuntu but it didn't work for me.

Comment: One of Oracle's primary goals in moving forward was complete backward-compatibility, so I'd assume that if 1.7 doesn't work but 1.5 does, then there is a deeper problem.

Comment: Whatever, my question still remains, I just want to install older version? Please can anyone tell me how should I do that?

Comment: I also installed jdk 1.5, maybe but it still shows version 1.7, maybe I can somehow switch versions now?

Comment: Beware the security risk here - 1.5 is ancient and has a TON of vulnerabilities that can be exploited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And select lower version from the list, and now it worked!

Answer (score 5):

You can keep multiple versions of Java (JRE and JDK) at a time and choose between them which one to use.

Go to following website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html

download the following file;

```
Java Development Kit 5.0 Update 22  47.46 MB    jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin
```

In a terminal window and go to the folder where your downloaded file is kept.

type the following;

```
sudo mv jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin /usr/lib/jvm
cd /usr/lib/jvm
chmod +x jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin
./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" \
"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java" 2

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" \
"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/javac" 2
```

You can switch between the installed versions of Java using the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Confirm the version of Java currently in use with these commands:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Comment: can you help me to configure firefox java 1.5 plugin? I don't found libnpjp2.so. Thank you so much